# Get every deal from a pipeline in hubspot

Tags: java, hubspot

In Hubspot, we have different pipelines. Now I'd like to use the api to fetch every deal that is in a specific pipeline. I know how to get the pipelines, but hupspot doesn't seem to have an api for *get me every deal that is in a specific pipeline*. It only has an api for "Get me a specific deal" and it needs a dealId.

Is it still possible to somehow get every deal from a pipeline?